# How to configure Tomcat AccessLogValve to hide passwords?

Tags: logging, tomcat7, tomcat-valve

Is it possible to configure AccessLogValve to hide/replace passwords before they are written to the log file?  I am not familiar with valves, perhaps there is a way to insert a custom filter/valve?

Answer (score 5):

### Solution with custom AccessLogValve class

1. Create a separate maven project:

   **pom.xml**

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
       <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

       <groupId>test</groupId>
       <artifactId>filtered-access-log-valve</artifactId>
       <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

       <dependencies>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
               <artifactId>tomcat-catalina</artifactId>
               <version>7.0.70</version>
           </dependency>
       </dependencies>

   </project>
   ```

   **FilteredAccessLogValve.java**

   ```
   package test;

   import org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve;

   public class FilteredAccessLogValve extends AccessLogValve {
       @Override
       public void log(String message) {
           super.log(message.replaceAll("password=[^&]*", "password=***"));
       }
   }
   ```
2. Build jar artifact from the project and copy it to **tomcat/lib/**
3. In **tomcat/conf/server.xml** change access log valve class

   `<Valve className="test.FilteredAccessLogValve" ...>`

### Another solution using servlet filter

Finally I came to this solution as it requires minimal tomcat configuration.

1. In **tomcat/conf/context.xml** turn off the default access log valve by commenting the `<Valve>` tag.
2. Create **AdvancedAccessLogFilter** class:

   ```
   package your.package;

   import javax.servlet.*;
   import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
   import java.io.IOException;

   public class AdvancedAccessLogFilter implements Filter {

       private static final String PASSWORD_REGEX = "password=[^&]+";
       private static final String PASSWORD_MASK = "password=***";
       private FilterConfig filterConfig = null;

       public void destroy() {
           this.filterConfig = null;
       }

       public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
           if (filterConfig == null) {
               return;
           }

           HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;

           String maskedPath = request.getRequestURI()
                   + (request.getQueryString() == null ? "" : request.getQueryString().replaceAll(PASSWORD_REGEX, PASSWORD_MASK))
                   + " "
                   + request.getProtocol();

           request.setAttribute("maskedPath", maskedPath);
           chain.doFilter(request, servletResponse);
       }

       public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
           this.filterConfig = filterConfig;
       }

       public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
           this.filterConfig = filterConfig;
       }        
   }
   ```
3. Register the servlet filter in your project's **web.xml**:

   ```
   <filter>
       <filter-name>AdvancedAccessLogFilter</filter-name>
       <filter-class>your.package.AdvancedAccessLogFilter</filter-class>
   </filter>
   <filter-mapping>
       <filter-name>AdvancedAccessLogFilter</filter-name>
       <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>
   ```
4. Create **src/main/webapp/META-INF/context.xml** with modified access log valve pattern:

   ```
   <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>    
   <Context>
       <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
       <Valve
               className='org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve'
               directory='logs'
               prefix='localhost_access_log.'
               suffix='.txt'
               pattern='%h %t %m "%{maskedPath}r" %s %b %D'
       />
   </Context>
   ```

If you want to autowire some beans from the Spring context, add `SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);`
to the filter's `init()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer is to extend the AccessLogValve class and override the log method, using String#replaceAll to replace all occurrences of the password with "***".

Comment: How should I distinguish between passwords and not passwords?

Comment: @Michael in the examples, the password is coming after a query parameter. If you don't know how to find the password in the logged data, then you're not going to be able to filter them out.

Answer (score 0):

Encountered the same problem in one of the SAP/Hybris Project which uses an embedded tomcat server. Where User and OAuth client's confidential information getting logged in the access logs in below format, whenever an oauth/token call is being made with password grant type.

```
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [31/Mar/2021:21:19:38 +0530] "POST /authorizationserver/oauth/token?client_id=trusted_client&client_secret=secret&grant_type=password&username=admin&password=nimda HTTP/1.1" 200 334 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.24.1"
```

**Solved Using Custom AccessLogValve class **

1. Create one standalone maven project.
2. Update Pom.xml as below

   4.0.0
   FilteredAccessLogValve
   filtered-access-log-valve
   0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
   Filtered Access Log valve
   Filtered Access Log valve For customizing Log Values


   org.apache.tomcat
   tomcat-catalina
   8.5.57





   maven-compiler-plugin
   3.5.1

   1.8
   1.8



   org.apache.maven.plugins
   maven-jar-plugin


   package

   jar
3. Create a class in src/main/java as FilteredAccessLogValve which extends AccessLogValve from org.apache.catalina.valves Package. The class looks like as below.

package org.apache.catalina.valves;

import java.io.CharArrayWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

```
public class FilteredAccessLogValve extends AccessLogValve {
    @Override
    public void log(CharArrayWriter message) {
        CharArrayWriter caw = new CharArrayWriter();
        try {
            caw.write(message.toString().replaceAll("password=[^&^ ]*", "password=***").replaceAll("client_secret=[^&^ ]*",
                    "client_secret=***"));
            super.log(caw);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            caw.close();
        }
    }
}
```

4. Build Jar using mvn clean -> mvn compile -> mvn install. Copy the filtered-access-log-valve-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT jar from /target folder and place it in the hybris/config/customize/platform/tomcat/lib folder.
5. look for all the *server*.xml hybris/config/tcServer/conf and hybris/config/tomcat/conf files and inside this replace all the valve class definition to new FilteredAccessLogValve class as below

Before:

```
<Valve  className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve"
                    directory="${HYBRIS_LOG_DIR}/tomcat"
                    prefix="access."
                    suffix=".log"
                    pattern="combined"
          />
```

After:

```
<Valve  className="org.apache.catalina.valves.FilteredAccessLogValve"
                    directory="${HYBRIS_LOG_DIR}/tomcat"
                    prefix="access."
                    suffix=".log"
                    pattern="combined"
          />
```

6. Run ant customize in the platform and then build and start the server.
7. Now the log will look like something as below

   0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [31/Mar/2021:21:19:38 +0530] "POST /authorizationserver/oauth/token?client_id=trusted_client&client_secret=***&grant_type=password&username=admin&password=*** HTTP/1.1" 200 334 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.24.1"